# Static Analysis for Junit

Tags: junit

Is there any Eclipse plugin for Static analysis of Junits. I am looking for some best tool like PMD which checks for Junit practises and gives me a report on errors.

Answer (score 0):

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) has been described as a strong compliment to PMD and should cover JUnit tests since JUnit is still just Java.  It's available from the [University of Maryland](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I am looking something which is specific to Junit Testing, for example no asserts in test method. or blank test methods and so on. I don't think PMD or Findbugs can detect such issues.